# get unique column values from multiple PySpark dataframes using a for loop condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 PySpark dataframes (`DF1` and `DF2`) and would like to loop over some of the columns (`colA`, `colB` from `DF1`; `colZ` from `DF2`) in the two dataframes and get distinct values.

DF1:

```
colA colB colC
    1    1    A
    3    1    Y
```

DF2:

```
colX colY colZ
   1    1  A21
   3    4  Y33
```

Output:

```
column value
colA        1
colA        3
colB        1
colZ      A21
colZ      Y33
```

This method works but trying to create a for loop and collect resultant distinct value doesn't work.. (since I have more than 50 dataframes)

```
df_combined = DF1.select('colA').dropDuplicates(['colA']).withColumn("new_column",lit("colA")).union(DF1.select('colB').dropDuplicates(['colB']).withColumn("new_column", lit("colB"))).union(DF2.select('colZ').dropDuplicates(['colZ']).withColumn("new_column", lit("colZ")))

df_combined.withColumnRenamed("colA", "column").withColumnRenamed("new_column", "value").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear as to what you're trying to achieve here but this is how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA': [1, 3], 'colB': [1, 1], 'colC': ['A', 'Y']})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'colX': [1, 3], 'colY': [1, 4], 'colZ': ['A21', 'Y33']})

DF1 = DF1.stack().reset_index()[['level_1',0]].rename(columns={'level_1':'column',0:'value'}).drop_duplicates(subset=['column', 'value'])
def transformAndAppend(df):
    df = df.stack().reset_index()[['level_1', 0]].rename(columns={'level_1': 'column', 0: 'value'}).drop_duplicates(subset=['column', 'value'])
    return DF1.append(df)

DF1 = transformAndAppend(DF2)

DF1 = DF1.loc[(DF1['column'] == 'colA') | (DF1['column'] == 'colB') | (DF1['column'] == 'colZ')]
print(DF1)
```